# How to ask If I fail or not in the job apply after taking the home test?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, applications, follow-up

I'm trying to apply on 'A company' for 'Junior Web Developer'
I got some emails after sending my resume, and the company gave me 'home test' and I already sent my answer. But it's been a week since I sent my answer and there's no feedback. is it okay if I ask the hr to follow up my test result? how to I ask?

Comment: @PhilipKendall okay then.. I did not get the job. thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, do follow up.

During the email exchanges, it should have been clear what the next steps would be and when you would hear back.  If there's no indications of time scales in your emails, then check back to ask when you can expect a response.

Sometimes, no response means you didn't get the job, so make sure.